# Call the address of a variable for a C function in matlab

Tags: c, matlab, pointers, dll, memory-address

I created a .dll in C and there are functions in it which change a variable by calling its address.  I have a piece of code which using some of the function in C:

```
char logfile[1000] = "i.log";
bool bRet = OpenDevice(logfile);
//FindHardware
int model;
int *ptr = &model;
char name_buffer[1000], sn_buffer[1000];
FindHardware(ptr, name_buffer, 1000, sn_buffer, 1000);
printf("Hardware found: %s", name_buffer);
```

The model variable is altered along with the name_buffer and sn_buffer.  Now I'm trying to replicate this code for matlab and I fiqured that this should work exactly the same:

```
header = 'header.h'; % url for header
dll = 'dll.dll'; % url for .dll
loadlibrary(dll, header);

logfile = 'i.log';
bRet = calllib('dll', 'OpenDevice', logfile);

model_number = 0;
% FindHardware
name_buffer = blanks(1000);
sn_buffer = blanks(1000);
model_number_pointer = libpointer('int32Ptr', model_number);
calllib('dll', 'FindHardware', model_number_pointer, name_buffer, 1000, sn_buffer, 1000);
```

But none of the variables are altered.  I imagine that it has something to do with the pointer that I created, is there some other way to access the address of model_number?

Comment: You mean `model_number_pointer.Value` is still 0?   And why no pointers for the other values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot believe that I went searching through 50+ pages until I finally found this answer.  It's simple, Matlab returns each argument of the function called in calllib and returns it as an array.  All that I had to do is this:

```
[irrelevant, model_number, name_buffer, sn_buffer] = calllib('dll', 'FindHardware', 0, blanks(1000), 1000, blanks(1000), 1000); % bufferSize  should be  atleast 16 bytes long
```

and all of the correct variables are returned for model_number, name_buffer, and sn_buffer

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use [MATLAB's pointers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/working-with-pointers.html), the `lib.pointer` class, for all output arguments.  You may also need to set the data type of each one.

```
model_number = int32(0);
modelPtr = libpointer('int32Ptr',model_number);

name_buffer = blanks(1000);
nameBufPtr = libpointer('stringPtr',name_buffer);

sn_buffer = blanks(1000);
snBufPtr = libpointer('stringPtr',name_buffer);

calllib('dll', 'FindHardware', modelPtr , nameBufPtr , 1000, snBufPtr, 1000);
```

Does that help?  Perhaps `libfunctionsview dll` will shed some light on the correct syntax.  You may also wish to get an output argument to help debug (`out = calllib(...)`).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I already tried that route.  It's useful to get most values if you return the values with get(ptr, 'Value') but it doesn't work with a char * (stringPtr returns **char).  The answer that I found was much more simple and efficient than creating pointers anyways.

Comment: @AbsentLung I'm glad that worked.  Note I suggested looking at the output parameters from `calllib`, but I didn't know it mapped each one of the inputs that way.  Good info, thanks.